# Minimal polynomial of $\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}$

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

Minimal polynomial of $\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}$

My try:$$x=\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}$$
$$(2x-1)^2=5$$$$x^2-x-1=0$$ i.e of degree 2.Please check.

Comment: Minimal polynomial over what field? $\mathbb Q$?

Comment: yes minimal polynomial over $\mathbb Q$

Comment: it is fine to me!

Comment: May I ask what is your definition of a minimal polynomial?

Comment: lowest degree monic polynomial for which $\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}$ is a root over  $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: Strictly speaking, you only showed that $x^2-x-1$ is *some* polynomial having $\frac{\sqrt 5+1}2$ as root. But of course it is indeed minimal because any smaller polynomial would have to be linear, i.e., $\frac{\sqrt 5+1}{2}\in\Bbb R$ - which is absurd.

Answer (score 1):

One process of finding the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ for a simple field extension $K(\alpha):K$ is to first find **a polynomial** with $\alpha$ as a root, then to prove (or at least argue) that **it has the least degree** among all such polynomials.

You have successfully found **a polynomial**, which is $x^2-x-1=0$.  Now, how to prove that this polynomial has the least possible degree, *i.e.* $2$?

When a quadratic polynomials is nominated as the minimal polynomial, we deploy the tactic [mentioned by *@HagenvonEitzen*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2135013/minimal-polynomial-of-frac-sqrt512#comment4395655_2135013) and attempt a proof by condradiction:

Assume that the minimal polynomial is of degree $1$, then it is of the form $x-\alpha$.  In our case, it's $x-\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}$.  A minimal polynomial must have coefficients in $K$ ($\mathbb{Q}$ in our case), but $\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}\not\in\mathbb{Q}$ because $\sqrt{5}\not\in\mathbb{Q}$.  Therefore, the minimal polynomial of $\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ cannot have degree $1$ and hence must have a degree of $2$ and above, which means that your polynomial
$$
  x^2-x-1=0
$$
is indeed the minimal polynomial of $x^2-x-1=0$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.